# ChromelyResponse.Status is ignored

Tags: c#, .net, cefsharp

I would like to return a http code 404 with `ChromelyResponse`. But its ignored and replaced by 200 code.

jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: myLocalUrlToCsharp,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    accepts: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    complete: function (output) {

        // output is always:
        // {
        //  readyState: 4,
        //  responseText: "{\"Data\":\"No Data\"}",
        //  responseJSON : {"Data":"No Data"},
        //  status: 200,
        //  statusText: "Ok"
        // }
    }
});
```

C#

```
using Chromely.Core.RestfulService;
...

private static ChromelyResponse Connect(ChromelyRequest request)
{
    return new ChromelyResponse(request.Id)
    {
        Status = 404,
        StatusText = "Not Found",
        Data = "No Data"
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain my mistake?
I use chromely with CefSharp.

*Note: Can someone add the tags `chromely` or `chromelyapps` please? I don't have enough reputation.*

[Github Chromely](https://github.com/chromelyapps/Chromely)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The status is set based on the success (or failure) of a request processing. It was not designed to be part of response data itself. If you want a status as part of the "content" then it will be part of the data, using the "Data" property.

```
private static ChromelyResponse Connect(ChromelyRequest request)
{
    var content = new SomeClass() {
        Status = 404,
        StatusText = "Not Found",
        Data = "No Data"
    }
    return new ChromelyResponse(request.Id)
    {
        Data = content
    }
}
```

The alternative is to create a custom HTTP Scheme handler to override default behavior. Please see..[Register New Scheme](https://github.com/chromelyapps/Chromely/wiki/Restful-Resources)

---

Copy and paste of @mattkol : [ChromelyResponse.Status is ignored](https://github.com/chromelyapps/Chromely/issues/110).